# Is is possible to form a 3D object from the front, side, top views with a triangle, a square and a circle respectively?

Tags: technical-drawing

A friend of mine asked me this question, but I don't know if it is possible or not. If it is possible, please show me how to construct it. If it is not possible, please prove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: object]

Created in Fusion 360, this is a 3D object with a cross section of a circle when viewed from above, a triangle when viewed from one side and a square when viewed from another side 90 degrees from the first.

ortho views below:

[image: circle cross section]

[image: square cross section]

[image: triangle cross section]

The process is thus:

1. sketch and extrude a square, creating a cube. select a face/plane,
2. sketch and extrude a triangle, boolean intersect the two solids
3. select a face/plane, sketch and extrude a circle, boolean intersect.

This is the sequence in creating an ambigram, a three dimensional object in which the appearance changes when viewed from different (orthogonal) angles.

Comment: Reminds me of some screwdriver bits.